# Null-coalescing operator - Which of the following do you prefer?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In your opinion what is more readable: ?? (operator) or use of if's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324331/in-your-opinion-what-is-more-readable-operator-or-use-of-ifs)

Let's say you have a method that checks is a list is null. If so, it instantiates it.

Generally, we'd do this:

```
if (StringList == null)
    StringList = new List<string>();
```

I've recently learned about null-coalescing operator and am tempted to change that to:

```
StringList = StringList ?? new List<string>();
```

It's more compact and looks like it'll be compiled to the same set of instructions as the 'traditional' method.

Probably a bit pedantic, but I was wondering if you have any reservations against such a method and which you'd actually use.

Comment: I'd use the shorter one. Any C# programmer worth his weight in salt knows about the `??` operator(or at least is easily taught)

Comment: Note that they are not quite the same [if StringList is a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403316/coalesce-operator-usage-c/5403354#5403354)..

Comment: possible duplicate of [In your opinion what is more readable: ?? (operator) or use of if's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324331/in-your-opinion-what-is-more-readable-operator-or-use-of-ifs) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1791852/310574

Comment: Interesting. So in the case of a property, it would be more efficient to not use the ?? operator. The setter will still be called even if it's a reference to the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your team. Not everybody can understand the ?? operator but it is cleaner. Once you get used to it, it is a good approach. I still stick with the if checks though. You never know who'll be updating your code.

Comment: Any decent programmer will either already know what it means, or ask someone (once)

Comment: You'd be suprised to know what "decent programmers" don't know..

Comment: My point is that if they're "decent", they will ask, and then they will know.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of properties, there is an interesting syntax:

```
private someType foo;
public SomeType Foo {
    get { return foo ?? (foo = {init}); }
}
```

This 1-liner can use a dup stloc rather than storing and loading the field separately. For example:

```
private List<string> foo;
public List<string> Foo {
    get { return foo ?? (foo = new List<string>()); }
}
```

A micro-optimisation, maybe - but quite cute.